# will it make a difference in the social security payment between taking at age 67 and 68

Tags: social-security

I am turning 68 in January . Should I wait to apply for my Social security payments. 
How is the payment calculated .will it increase if I don't apply now?

Answer (score 3):

Each year from full retirement age to age 70 raises your benefit by 8% plus the COLA. If you are in good health, better to wait.

Comment: Please remember, however, that although your payments will be 8% higher, you will receive 12 fewer.

Comment: @chili555: Not necessarily, since (except in a few cases) you don't know how long you will live after starting to collect.  Perhaps the 8% extra will be like Micawber's sixpence, allowing you to live in happiness rather than misery, so you wind up living longer.

Comment: @chili555 - that's why i referenced the health issue. See Dilip's answer, he went into far more detail.

Comment: It's prorated by months, so every month that you delay collecting, your payment increases 0.66%

Answer (score 2):

Each year from full retirement age to age 70, your monthly benefit increases if you delay the start of retirement benefits. The rationale for the increase is that the total SS benefit if you live exactly as long as your life expectancy is the same in either case.  The life expectancy is longer at age X than it is at age X+1, and so you get a smaller benefit for a longer time if you start taking SS benefits at age X or a larger benefit for a shorter time if you start taking SS benefits at age X+1. Assuming, of course, that you are an average law-abiding person and will live exactly as long as the Social Security Administration's tables of life expectancy say you can be expected to live.  On the other hand, as JoeTaxpayer's answer says, if you are in good health, it is better to wait and continue to receive a (larger) benefit even when you are way past the age when Social Security expected you to die. If you are in poor health and might not make it to your life expectancy, start SS benefits sooner, possibly even before reaching full retirement age, so that you can collect as much as possible before you pass on. Contrary to what many believe, there is no pot of money containing all your contributions over the years (plus earnings) with your name on it in Social Security with your heirs receiving what is left in the pot when you pass on; that's the IRA model, not the Social Security model. So, get yours while the going is good if you are in poor health but wait till 70 if you are in good health; your 90-year old future self will be glad of the extra money coming in.  And of course, you could drop dead from a stroke caused by undiagnosed (or ignored) high blood pressure ("the silent killer") the day after your 70th birthday and not receive a dime in Social Security benefits....